# Reading JSON file from raw or asset folder - android

Tags: java, android, json, inputstream

this is my code and I tried many different way to find a way to read the json file. I made it database.json then I tried database.txt . It was in res/raw folder now I copied also in asset folder, but nothing is helpful. can you please check it is you see anything incorrect.

I get a NullPointerException 
and in the LogCat is always go to :

```
System.out.println("opening file");
```

and then is stops. Any advise would be appreciated. I'm really desperate to find solution.

```
public static JSONObject parseJSON() throws IOException, JSONException{

    String JSONString = null;
    JSONObject JSONObject = null;
    System.out.println("opening file");
    InputStream is = context.getAssets().open("database.txt");
    int size = is.available();
    //stores whole data
    System.out.println("reading file");
    byte[] bytes = new byte[size];
    //reader
    is.read(bytes);
    is.close();
    JSONString = new String(bytes, "UTF-8");
    JSONObject = new JSONObject(JSONString);

    return JSONObject;

}
```

Comment: your context is probably null

Comment: oh okay. how can I change that. I just try to get the context of the app in order to get to the folder.

Comment: First, don't use System.out to print info in Android.  Use `Log.i("MyTag", "message")`, or other methods on the `Log` class.  Second, there's not a really easy way to get your hands on a context in a static method.  Generally, static methods take a Context as an argument, and if you're calling it from a Service or Activity, you just pass `this`.

Comment: @PammGupta: usually, the context being quite a volatile thing, it is customary to explicitely pass it to every method that needs it. You're method would be `JSONObject parseJSON(Context context)`